# How do I return the user input value inside of a while loop?

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, return, do-while

I want to return userYear, or in other words, the input the user gives me. It tells me to initialize the variable outside the loop. When I do that, it tells me the variable is duplicated. What I want to do is simply return the input so that my other program methods can use them.

```
public static int readTheYear() {
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean correctYear = false;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter theyear:");
        int userYear = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        if(userYear > 2025)
        correctYear = true;
        
        else 
        System.out.println("Invalid. Try again.");
        
    }
    while (!correctYear);

    correctYear = false;
    return userYear; // gives an error
    
}
```

Comment: Just return from the middle of the method. At that point, you don't need `correctYear` at all - your loop can just be `while (true)` because you'll return when the value is appropriate. If you want to keep your current structure, you could declare `userYear` before the loop *instead of* where you currently declare it - just assign to it in your current joint declaration+assignment.

Comment: The way you wrote your code your variable `userYear` is visible only **inside** your `do-while` block.

Comment: If I do that method, the loop won't work. What I need is for it to keep looping every time it's incorrect to the first message.

Comment: As it was already mentioned, having `int userYear;` declared before the do-while loop will have it be visible at your `return` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic idea:

```
int userYear;
...
do {
    ...
    userYear = ...  // no 'int' here!!
    ...
} while (...);
...
return userYear;
```

Note 1: no need for  `if`, just `correctYear = userYear > 2025;`

Note 2: no need for `correctYear` at all:

```
int userYear;
...
do {
    ...
    userYear = ...
    // no if here
    ...
} while (userYear <= 2025);
...
return userYear;
```

---

alternative, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66126672/how-do-i-return-the-user-input-value-inside-of-a-while-loop/66127066#comment116910402_66126672) by Jon:

```
...
while(true) {
    ...
    int useYear = ...
    if (...) {
        return useYear;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is declare the variable "userYear" outside the while loop. That's because the while loop has it own scope, and variables declared inside of it only works in this loop.
Read more about scope in Java

Comment: Of course you can do the solution proposed by Jon (it is correct). But I'm explaining why your code is failing.